# How do I serialize and deserialize the public key for ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, openssl, cryptography

I'm trying to port my key exchange setup to dotnet core (preview 3.0) with Linux support. For Linux support it seems I need to be using the `ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl` class available in `System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl` on Nuget. I can't figure out how to serialize and deserialize the public key to communicate between the server and client.

Using the equivalent CNG class (ECDiffieHellmanCng) you would simply call

```
ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray()
```

to serialize the key into a byte array, then once the key has been sent to the other party, that party would import it using

```
EncKeyBlob = ecdh.DeriveKeyMaterial(CngKey.Import(otherpublickey, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob));
```

However, calling `ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray()` on ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl throws `Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.` on Ubuntu 18.04.

Additionally, I cannot see any `CngKey.Import()` equivalent for the OpenSSL version of the class.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58658396/1462295

Answer (score 0):

Export the public key using `byte[] alicePublicKey = alice`.

To create a derived key create a new instance of `ECDiffieHellman` (using .Create()) and then import the public key into this instance.

```
    // computer 1:
    using var alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create();
    byte[] alicePublicKey = alice.PublicKey.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo();
    
    // on computer 2, assuming we got alicePublicKey from computer 1:
    using var bob = ECDiffieHellman.Create();
    
    using var alice = ECDiffieHellman.Create();
    alice.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(alicePublicKey, out _);
    var sharedKey = bob.DeriveKeyMaterial(alice.PublicKey);
```