# How to implement Diffie Hellman in .netcore/Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, cryptography, diffie-hellman

`ECDiffieHellmanCng` -> Platform not supported

`ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl` -> `PublicKey.ToByteArray()` -> Platform not supported

Here's basically the same (unanswered) question from someone else, 7 months ago
[How do I serialize and deserialize the public key for ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366299/how-do-i-serialize-and-deserialize-the-public-key-for-ecdiffiehellmanopenssl-on)

I'd like to avoid pulling in 3rd party deps if there's a way to tame the provided classes.

Answer (score 1):

`ECDiffieHellmanCng` is not supported on Linux.

Linux uses `ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl`, but note

> The types involved do not translate between platforms

See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1841042b99062de13dc80098cede9413be569238/Documentation/architecture/cross-platform-cryptography.md

You can find some examples of how this is used in the test suite, for example

```
[Fact]
public void VerifyDuplicateKey_ValidHandle()
{
    using (var first = new ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl())
    using (SafeEvpPKeyHandle firstHandle = first.DuplicateKeyHandle())
    using (ECDiffieHellman second = new ECDiffieHellmanOpenSsl(firstHandle))
    using (ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey firstPublic = first.PublicKey)
    using (ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey secondPublic = second.PublicKey)
    {
        byte[] firstSecond = first.DeriveKeyFromHash(secondPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        byte[] secondFirst = second.DeriveKeyFromHash(firstPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
        byte[] firstFirst = first.DeriveKeyFromHash(firstPublic, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);

        Assert.Equal(firstSecond, secondFirst);
        Assert.Equal(firstFirst, firstSecond);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl/tests/EcDiffieHellmanOpenSslTests.cs

Comment: Where's P and G to share with the client? Are they hardcoded and I just get `firstFirst` and send that to the client? `ECDiffieHellmanPublicKey firstPublic = D.PublicKey;` still can't be serialized. If I call ".ToByteArray()" I get another `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`

I can't figure out how to get the key out of the class so I can share it with my client over a socket..

Answer (score 0):

With .NET Core 3.0 you can serialize the value with `key.ExportSubjectPublickeyInfo()` (and rehydrate one with `key.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(bytes, out _)`.

If you’re staying on 2.1 (LTS) you can use ExportParameters/ImportParameters with custom serialization logic.